# wmctrl not working in crontab

Tags: linux, shell

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu). I use `wmctrl` to make the `firefox` window always on top. And it worked FINE when I run the shell on a **terminal**.

Here is my shell code (say that it was `/usr/app/keepfront.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
WINTITLE="Mozilla Firefox" # Main Firefox window has this in titlebar
PROGNAME="firefox mywebsite --sync" #run the firefox program

#Use wmctrl to list all windows, count how many contain WINTITLE
WINCOUNT=wmctrl -l | grep -c "$WINTITLE"

if [ $WINCOUNT != 0 ]
then
    wmctrl -a "$WINTITLE" # If it exists, bring window to front
else
    $PROGNAME & # Otherwise, just launch ff
fi
exit 0
```

I would like to use crontab to run the shell every 1 minute. Crontab DID run the shell (I wrote some echos), but **nothing happened**.

Here is my crontab code:

```
*/1 * * * *   /usr/app/keepfront.sh
```

Anyone know WHY? How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cron` jobs do not have access to your environment variables, although they are owned by the user they do not run in that user's full desktop environment. In this case your script does not know about your `DISPLAY` environment variable. To retrieve information and to make changes `wmctrl` needs to know which `DISPLAY` to use.

To do what you want to do, all you need is to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable in your script **before** any calls to `wmctrl`. Assuming you only have 1 monitor the line below should fix your problem (my test worked fine). If you have more than 1 monitor then just use `echo $DISPLAY` on the command line to help you configure the command for your various monitors.

```
# Add to your script before any calls to wmctrl.
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Some other things to note:

- If you have more than one 'Mozilla Firefox' window open then your code will only bring the first one encountered by `wmctrl` to the top, this will be the one that was opened first because `wmctrl` looks through windows from oldest to newest.
- I have not tested the launching of Firefox aspect of your script, genarally speaking I would have thought doing this is a bad idea because Firefox will also use environment variables which won't be set when running the script from `crontab`. You could find a list of all the environment variables that Firefox uses and then manually set them in the script...
- You do not need the `*/1` bit in your `crontab` line, just use: `* * * * * /usr/app/keepfront.sh` to run something every minute.
- You may wish to add some environment variables to the top of your `crontab` file - many people do for a variety of reasons. For instance the `PATH` in your `crontab` file probably won't be the same as your user `PATH` and your `LANG` variable won't be set either, this can stop regular expressions used in scripts called by `cron` from working. I have the following set at the **top** of my `crontab` file, like this:

```bash
# These are the basic paths, mine also includes my own scripts path.
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# Note: LANG allows grep regexes to work properly in called scripts.
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Hint: type `echo $PATH` and `echo $LANG` to get your current settings.

Typing `env` on your command line will show you all your environment variables, to see how limited those available to `cron` are, add this line to your `crontab`, don't forget to change the path I've used and to remove the line after it has run.

```
* * * * * env > /home/user/EnvOutputFromCrontab
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works great after adding 'export DISPLAY=:0'  and your advises are great.

Answer (score 1):

One part of your problem is that this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
WINCOUNT=wmctrl -l | grep -c "$WINTITLE"
```

It runs the command `-l` (which probably doesn't exist) with `WINCOUNT=wmctrl` as one of its environment variables.

You probably intended to write:

```
WINCOUNT=$(wmctrl -l | grep -c "$WINTITLE")
```

The other part of your problem may be that `wmctrl` and `firefox` don't work correctly when run without a terminal, as `crontab` runs its jobs without a terminal.  I've not tried running `firefox` from  `crontab`, and I can't think of anything much more annoying than having Firefox jump to the foreground every minute (OK; I can think of some things about equally annoying, but the concept doesn't bear thinking about).

Comment: You're right about the first point. WINCOUNT=$(wmctrl -l | grep -c "$WINTITLE") works and plus looks nicer. While I still need to keep ff always on top,do u have any idea?